# Проверка наличия якоря в ссылке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте.
Есть вот такой js скрипт

```
if(window.location.hash == '#box1') {
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].setAttribute("class", "mod");
        document.getElementsByClassName('one')[0].setAttribute("class", "none");
    }
```

Если таких якорей много, то плодить условие - плохой вариант. Вопрос как может сделать просто проверку "Если есть hash, то выполнить функции?

Comment: Как на счёт `window.location.hash.indexOf('#') !== -1`?

Comment: да на самом деле даже вариант window.location.hash вроде отрабатывает по нужному мне сценарию, но хотелось бы узнать правильный ли это подход или что-то ещё дописать нужно

Comment: Сложно ответить "Правильно ли?", если неизвестно что Вам нужно.

Comment: Всё просто - если в ссылке присутствует якорь (любой) - вешать определённые классы на определённые блоки.

Если более развернуто, то имеется окно приветсвия, по клику окно убирается, и юзер скроллится к нужному блоку (по id блока якоря сделаны) -> в ссылке появляется якорь нужного блока. Всё это действие идёт по средствам CSS. Поэтому и нужно вот такой скрипт проверки наличия якоря в ссылке, чтобы, если человек перезагрузил страницу с якорем, то окно приветствия ему уже не показывалось.